# Cannot add estimote sdk package to cordova

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, estimote

Newest Estimote SDK is bundled into aar project and I cannot add it as external library to my custom cordova plugin, it does copy the aar file and it created gradle library in project.proprties, but it **fails during build process** because it simply **cannot find com.estimote.sdk package in my plugin java files**.

```
Beacon.java:40: error: package com.estimote does not exist
```

What I've tried so far is adding aar file with these params:

```
<framework src="libs/estimote.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
<source-file src="libs/estimote-sdk-preview.aar" target-dir="libs" />
```

I've also tried:

- extracting aar to jar and adding it with source-file tag;
- changing source-file to resource-file tag;
- creating build-extras.gradle with compile 'com.estimote:estimote-sdk-preview:8.1@aar';
- adding aar as a new module with Android Studio.

It does copy and prepare everything, but it just cannot find library in the build process.

## SOLVED:

My fault while importing package in my java files, it **HAS** to be:

```
import com.estimote.sdk.*;
```